# Can Java GC collect instance, while it is used by method

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a simple question about Java GC. Some example :

```
Object instance = new Object();
longMethod(instance);

...

// First example
private void longMethod(Object arg) {
   Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60)
   // this method works 1hr. Does it keep reference to Object and GC canot release it?
}

//Seconde example
private void longMethod(Object arg) {
  arg = null;
  Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60)
  // we clear reference in method. Can GC relese Object now?
}
```

So what is lifecycle of "instance" in both cases? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is ***pass-by-value***: setting the local variable `arg` in the second method to null does not mean that the local variable in the caller method is also set to reference null. Therefore, the object in the caller still has a reference pointed to it.

Consider the case where you create a new object inside the method:

```
private void longMethod(Object arg) {
   arg = new Object();  // Line 1
   Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 60);
   arg = null;  // now the object created in line 1 is eligible for GC

}
```

In this case, the object created using `arg = new Object();` (which is different than the one created in the caller method) is *eligible* for GC.

And consider the case where you have this in the caller method:

```
Object instance = new Object();  // Line 1
longMethod(instance);   
instance = null; // now the object created in line 1 is eligible for GC (see note below)
```

Now the object previously created in Line 1 is also eligible for GC **assuming there are no references to the object that were created inside `longMethod`**.

Answer (score 5):

In both cases `Object instance`, which is a local variable of the method that calls `longMethod`, holds a reference to the instance, so the GC can't release it before the method that called `longMethod` ends.

Note that `arg = null` only sets the local reference inside `longMethod` to null. It doesn't change the value of the `instance` variable in the method that called `longMethod`.

Comment: Consider a call `longMethod(new Object());`. The caller has no way to access the object whose reference was passed to `longMethod`.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That's a different question. I think the GC will be able to release the instance in this case for the second example, since there won't be any references left to that object.